# HTTPServer как правильно составить response

Tags: c#, html, http

HTTP сервер работает на C#. При GET запросе он читает базу и что то возвращает.
Есть страница index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="sidemenu">
                    <div class="menuitem">menu1</div>
                    <div class="menuitem">menu2</div>
                    <div class="menuitem">menu3</div>
                    <div class="menuitem">menu4</div>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>::contentblock::</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
td{vertical-align: top;font-size: 14px;}
```

script.js

```
window.onload=function(){
    alert("hello")
}
```

сервер:

```
html = File.ReadAllText("D:/HTTPServer/index.html");
//...сбор данных из базы и формирование строк таблицы table tr td ....
html = html.Replace("::contentblock::", tbl);

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Stream output = response.OutputStream;
output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

output.Close();
```

Таблица приходит, но браузер выдает такие ошибки:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://192.168.1.149:1111/style.css".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'   script.js:1
```

Стили и скрипт не работают. Если же их прописать внутри html разметки то работают. Какой MIME тип нужно задать? И почему подключаемые файлы не работают?

Comment: Charset надо убрать из mime типа. Его можно в мету в сам html вставить. `<meta charset="utf-8">`. В типе просто оставить "text/html". Но не уверен, что в этом может быть проблема.

Comment: @aepot нет эффекта

Comment: Браузер запрашивает все части страниыы отдельно, и статику лучше отдавать напрямую, например с помощью Nginx или Apache сервера, а в .Net сервер перенаправлять только запросы, требующие обработки. Но это так, к слову. А так, не понятна причина, почему css приезжает с неверным mime. Код, показанный вами, не имеет отношения к отдаче css.